# How do I render colors in Reactjs with data api

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render colors in reactjs with data API, I have a json data in api:

```
      {
        "id": 1,
        "price": 50990000,
        "image": "https://i.ibb.co/9W0kQyN/i-Pad-Pro-11-in-Wi-Fi-Space-Gray.png",
        "ram": "2048 GB",
        "color": "Space Gray "
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "price": 22450000,
        "image": "https://i.ibb.co/G7DnrH6/i-Pad-Pro-11-in-Wi-Fi-Silver.png",
        "ram": "128 GB",
        "color": "Silver "
      },
options": [
      {
        "key": "color",
        "value": [
          "Space Gray ",
          "Silver "
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Also, I have the following json, so I would like to have the option of a click option to render value in page:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchApi = async () => {

            const result = await singleApi.singleApi(productId);
            if (result.message) {
                console.log(result.message)
                setIsLoading(false)
                setError(result.message);
            }

            else {

                setProductDetail(result.data.product_details);
                var dataFirst = result.data.product_details[0];
                // console.log(dataFirst)
                var checkRam = dataFirst.ram !== undefined ? `${dataFirst.ram}` : undefined;
                var checkStorage = dataFirst.storage !== undefined ? `${dataFirst.storage}` : undefined;
                var checkColor = dataFirst.color !== undefined ? `${dataFirst.color}` : undefined;
                var checkScreenSize = dataFirst['screen-size'] !== undefined ? `${dataFirst['screen-size']}` : undefined;
                setRamValue(checkRam);
                setPrice(dataFirst.price);
                setStorageValue(checkStorage);
                setImage(dataFirst.image);
                setColorValue(checkColor);
                setScreenSizeValue(checkScreenSize)
            }
        };

        fetchApi();
    }, [productId]);
useLayoutEffect(() => {
        var target =
            productDetail &&
            productDetail.find((item) => {
                var ram = ramValue === undefined ? ramValue : `${ramValue}`;
                var color = colorValue === undefined ? colorValue : `${colorValue}`;
                var storage = storageValue === undefined ? storageValue : `${storageValue}`;
                var screenSize = screenSizeValue === undefined ? screenSizeValue : `${screenSizeValue}`;
                return item.ram === ram && item.color === color && item.storage === storage && item['screen-size'] === screenSize;
            });
        // console.log(target)
        // var changeName = target !== undefined ? target.name : name;
        var changeId = target !== undefined ? target.id : idProduct;
        var changeImage = target !== undefined ? target.image : image;
        var changePrice = target !== undefined ? target.price : price;
        setIdProduct(changeId);
        // setName(changeName);
        setImage(changeImage);
        setPrice(changePrice);
        // console.log(result);
    }, [productDetail, ramValue, colorValue, storageValue, price, image, name, idProduct, screenSizeValue]);
const findColor = (color) => {
        setColorValue(color);
    };
return (
<div className={cx('option-color')}>
{option.value.map((value, idx) => 
(
    <div
    className={cx('space',`${value === colorValue ? 'active' : ''}`,)}
    key={idx}
    value={value}
    onClick={() => findColor(value)}
    >
        <div className={cx('radio-color')}
             style={{backgroundColor: {value}}}
        ></div>
    </div>
))}
</div>
)
```

When render 'space-gray' view '#333', 'Silver' = '#999', check options in color match to product have color => active to css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply define object to set color with value and use color value of backend as index of object

something like this :

```
  const colorCodes = {
    'Space Gray': '#333',
    'Silver': '#999',
  };
```

and in div tag :

```
 <div className={cx('radio-color')}
           style={{backgroundColor: colorCodes[value]}}
      ></div>
```